# Solr: Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: ajax, solr

I have a local Solr Server running on Jetty, and I am trying to use AJAX Solr to make queries to the server but the connection is refused:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8984/. Origin http://127.0.0.1:5000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I have gone through the tutorial from AJAX Solr: https://github.com/evolvingweb/ajax-solr/wiki with no issues with the example server.

Is there any way around this by modifying solr.config?

Comment: in jetty config port is 8984?

Comment: In this machine the default is 8984 instead of 8983 Im not sure why

Comment: @JorgeLazo: hey bro, found any solution for this?

Comment: I got the same problem. Anyone found a slution yet?